# Angularjs nested dependent promises

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the [$modal service from angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), but this question on promise structure is not specific to that module. In this case, I need to show an unknown number of modals, in order.  Rather than show them all at once I would like to wait for the result from one modal before displaying the next. One reason being that if a user cancels one modal, the rest won't display. Another reason is that I would like to instantiate the subsequent modal controller based on some information that was entered in the first.

I have put together a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ynp9IxhpcEIz4JbXxGSe) that has the functionality I want.

The code in my plunker is a convoluted mess of passing counters around. Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this?

Here is the messy part:

```
var myarr =[1,2,3,4];

$scope.open = function (size) { 
  var promises = [$q.defer()]
  for (var i=0; i<myarr.length; i++){
    promises.push($q.defer());
  }

  var modalInstance
  openThisModal = function(scope, i){
    return $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      scope: scope,
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        count: function(){ return i;},
      }
    });
  };
  for (var i=0; i<(promises.length-1); i++){
    var deferred = promises[i];
    deferred.promise.then(function(j){
      openThisModal($scope,j).result.then(function(result){ 
        promises[result.count].resolve(result.count+1);
      });
    });
  };
  promises[0].resolve(1);
};
```

Edit:
I updated the plunk to remove some of the passing back and forth. But still seems like more counters than I would like.

Comment: why can't you skip creating all the promises and pass data back through  modalController  `result` promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify it somewhat with recursion as long as it's not a large number of dialogs...

```
  var myarr =[1,2,3,4];

  var openModals = function(size, scope, numbers){
    if (numbers.length === 0) return;

    var nextNumber = numbers[0];

    $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
        $scope.ok = function () {
          $modalInstance.close();
        };
        $scope.cancel = function () {
          $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
        $scope.number = nextNumber;
      },
      scope: scope,
      size: size,
    }).result.then(function() {
      scope.selected = nextNumber;
      openModals(size, scope, numbers.slice(1));
    });
  };

  $scope.open = function (size) { 
    openModals(size, $scope, myarr);
  };
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/FYtz5UoasIN2FifyNfmR?p=preview)

Comment: Much better, thank you. I will remember the combination of slice and length 0 return.